# Out-String + TrimStart Command

Tags: powershell, vmware

The command `$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= Get-VM | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $server.Name} | fl Name | Out-String` gets me the following result "Name : bra-rj-cons-dc2.domain.org".

I´m trying to use the {$_.TrimStart('Name : ')} at the end of the pipeline but could´t find anything that works with Pipeline and Trim.

I just need to remove the "Name : " before writing in a CSV file.

Comment: Instead of ```fl Name``` use ```Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Name"``` - that will just pass the literal name value down the pipeline rather than formatting it with a "Name: " prefix.

Comment: The hole command is `$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= Get-VM | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $server.Name} | fl Name | Out-String {$_.TrimStart('Name : ')}`, but even using the `$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= Get-VM | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $server.Name} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Name" | Out-String`, now I have the error Is not possible to call a method with a Null Expression Value.

Comment: Instead of commenting on your own question you should update it. Just hit the [Edit] link and add what you forgot. 

Answer (score 0):

I had to figure it out another way to make it work. Here's the code for anyone that needs.

Obs:. I tried to put the code in the code sample, but could´t fill in the right way. Sorry for this.

Get-VM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Name" > C:\temp\sccm.txt

$file = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\sccm.txt

$servers = Get-CMCollection -Name "SRV_WU_SCCM_Mgmt" | Get-CMCollectionMember | Select-Object Name
$deploymentDate = Get-CMDeployment -CollectionName "SRV_WU_SCCM_Mgmt" | Select-Object EnforcementDeadline

ForEach ($server in $servers) {
ForEach ($line in $file) {

```
    if($line -match $server.Name + "." -and $line -NotMatch 'replica$'){
       
        $serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= $line.ToString()

    }        
}

$Column++
$serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)=$deploymentDate.EnforcementDeadline
    
#Check to see if space is near empty and use appropriate background colors
$range = $serverInfoSheet.Range(("A{0}"  -f $row),("G{0}"  -f $row))
$range.Select() | Out-Null

$Column = 1
$row++
```

}